# Terraform - embedded quotation marks

Tags: terraform

In Terraform I can use:

```
name = "${var.names["apple"])"
```

which looks up the string "apple" in `var.names`.

However, this syntax would break in most programming languages as it would try and parse `"${var.names["` then `apple` then `"])"`.

I've looked up documentation on this but failed to find anything. Are there any details?

I've read:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html
and
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html

The last link briefly gives an example

```
  template = "${file("templates/web_init.tpl")}"
```

but doesn't explain.

Comment: What are you actually asking?  How they can make this work?  I suspect that's just down to their parser, which I assume looks for `${..}` over anything else, then works outwards

Comment: I thought I'd been pretty clear -> Are there any details on this syntax? It's a little annoying having to guess the syntax when it's actually very anti-intuitive given the syntax would break in most programming languages.

Comment: Right, I agree with you there - I do feel I'm fighting the syntax a lot of the time.  On your second link, it does say _"Embedded within strings in Terraform, whether you're using the Terraform syntax or JSON syntax, you can interpolate other values. These interpolations are wrapped in ${}, such as ${var.foo}."_  I guess coupled with the fact that those interpolations can then contain map variables etc sort of explains it, but yes - not very explicitly

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-map-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Upgrade guide](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-7.html#nested-quotes-and-escaping) to v0.7 explicitly introduces nested quoting context. Apparently this had been allowed since one of the earlier versions, but I could not pinpoint which one exactly.